# Get OAuth Header from URL

Tags: c#, oauth, http-headers

I have a third party URL which sends the oAuth parameters in the header. When i am reading it using the below code the Authorization parameters are not being returned. What am i missing?

```
string url = "http:  // xxx.com/events/abc-def";
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            string authHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

Comment: Did you try to review the response instead of the request, I mean you are doing the request, I am understanding that the authorization is generated from string url = "http:  // xxx.com/events/abc-def"; right ?

Comment: Yes, the authorization is generated from the URL. The response is throwing a 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: can you inspect the request using fiddler ? I think that you need to get the authorization token before to make a GET request, could you try with WebRequestMethods.Http.Head ?